# how to change added Combobox item in datagridview when Data Source changes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I added two `datagridview` in a from. `datagridview1` named `lotDetailDataGridView` and its column named `Quality` getting its data from sql database and `datagridview2` named `pieceDetailDataGridView` and its column named `quality` is a combobox column and getting items from column `Quality` of `lotDetailDataGridView` like this:

[image: Cell value is not valid error]

I am doing this to get items for column `Quality` of `lotDetailDataGridView`:

```
private void addQualityToCombo()
    {
        string[] val = new string[lotDetailDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < lotDetailDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
                if (lotDetailDataGridView[1, i].Value != null)
                {
                    val[i] = lotDetailDataGridView[1, i].Value.ToString();
                    pieceDetailQualityColumn.DataSource = val;
                }
        }
    }
        
    private void lotDetailDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        addQualityToCombo();
    }
```

All I want is when I change a value in `pieceDetailDataGridView's` `quality` column it should automatically be updated on  `lotDetailDataGridView's` `Quality` column. Please take a look at the reference I added above.
My attempt of doing this is giving an error.
Please guide me and thanks.

Comment: By deselecting the value `Cadbury` in `lotDetailDataGridView`, you removed it from the list of possible values in `pieceDetailDataGridView`.  But you still have a cell with `Cadbury` selected in `pieceDetailDataGridView`.  That's why you see the error.  You're trying to select a value that's no longer in your combobox list.  You must decide how you want this value to be handled before leaving the `CellEndEdit` method handler.

Comment: thats what i want like when i change Cadbury from  lotDetailDataGridView it should automatically be updated on  pieceDetailDataGridView. and new value take place of old value. i dont know how to do that. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use dataGridView2_EditingControlShowing event and ComboBox_SelectedValueChanged event to update the column.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column1","Name");
            var list = Getlist();
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cmb.HeaderText = "Quantity";
            cmb.Name = "cmb";
            cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 6;
            cmb.DataSource = list;
            cmb.DataPropertyName = "comboboxValue";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("column2", "Weight");
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            cmb1.HeaderText = "Quantity";
            cmb1.Name = "cmb";
            cmb1.MaxDropDownItems = 6;
            cmb1.DataSource = list;
            cmb1.DataPropertyName = "comboboxValue";
            dataGridView2.Columns.Add(cmb1);
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        }
        public List<string> Getlist()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string connstr = connstr";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Quantity from Product", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                string result = reader[0].ToString();
                list.Add(result);
               
            }
            connection.Close();
            return list;

        }
        private void dataGridView2_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }
        private void dataGridView2_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView2.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.Control is ComboBox)
            {
                ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
                comboBox.SelectedValueChanged -= ComboBox_SelectedValueChanged;
                comboBox.SelectedValueChanged += ComboBox_SelectedValueChanged;
            }
        }

        private void ComboBox_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var text = ((ComboBox)sender).Text;
            int rowindex = dataGridView2.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            int count = dataGridView2.RowCount;
            int rowcount = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            if (count != rowcount)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(1);
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value = text;
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much @jack. you are always been so helpful. i got a way how to do it by your answer. thanks